# Residual Plot of multiple regression centered on (0,2)

Tags: regression, residuals

There's a lot of great questions and answers here about funny-looking residual plots. Mine isn't - it's kinda normal, except it's centered on (0, 2)  [Cartesian coordinates],  not on (0,0). Any idea what this might mean?

[image: my residual plot]

My own (precarious) guess is that somewhere a constant is missing, but since the regression model does have an intercept, I feel I'm overlooking something obvious. Any help, please?

Comment: Presumably this is at most a _multiple_ regression, not _multivariate_. A multivariate regression has several outcome or response variables bundled together.

Comment: What is the basis for your expectation that your model will center all its predictions around zero?

Comment: @whuber - all the examples I've looked at so far (I'm a self-taught noob) were (0,0), so naively I took it that this was the goal. In my dataset, the mean of the targets is 2.1 - so Martin Modrák's guidance was spot-on.

Comment: @Nick Cox, yes, you are right, I should have said *multiple*. My regression will end up producing multiple target variables, but here I was checking a single one (hope I make sense!). Many thanks.

Comment: You were probably looking at examples where first the response had been centered, so that on average the prediction should be zero, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This - to me - looks like a perfectly healthy residual plot. It would be problematic if your residuals (vertical axis) were not centered on 0, but the predicted values are just centered wherever your responses are centered, which in this case happens to be two.

Comment: Ah, thanks Martin. So the x values simply relate to the target values of my regression (which ranges between 0 and 4). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes. It could actually be a sign of a problem if the "Predicted" results had vastly different scale than your target.